# Clear input field reset back to defaultValue (0)

Tags: reactjs

If I clear the input (by manually deleting the value) it leaves an empty field - how do I have this reset back to 0 when I manually delete the value? So as soon as the field contains no value set default to 0.

```js
<TextField
  type='number'
  defaultValue='0'
  InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
  id='standard-basic'
  label='NUMBER (kg)'
  value={mynumber}
  onChange={(e) => setMyNumber(parseInt(e.currentTarget.value))}
  name='MyNumber'
  variant='outlined'
/>;
```

I also have a `useState(0)` on `setMyNumber`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are using Material UI's TextField component. As stated in the documentation, default value is only displayed when your component is uncontrolled. Here you have a controlled component.

https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/

What you can do is providing onChange a function check whether `e.target.value` is empty ("") or not, so you can set your variable to 0 or `e.target.value`.

```
handleChange = (e) => {
  if (e.target.value === "" && mynumber !== 0) {
    setMyNumber(0)
  } else {
    setMyNumber(e.target.value)
  }
}
<TextField
  onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks - but how would I modify my inline onChange={(e) => setMyNumber(parseInt(e.currentTarget.value))} to represent this blank value?

Comment: Ternary operator would help you with that: onChange={(e) => e.target.value === "" ? setMyNumber(0) : setMyNumber(e.target.value)}

Comment: OK, this kinda works - but logistically it does not - if you remove the contents of the field it defaults to 0 but I cannot actually delete the 0 to put this number in as 10 - it only allows me to put 010

Comment: I have updated the solution with an extra condition to check if the current state is 0. So you would be able to delete the 0 and have an empty input field.